How can I filter the results of IMPORTFEED based on a range containing a list of keywords?

I have the following working Google Sheets IMPORTFEED formula in a sheet named 'RSS':
=IMPORTFEED("https://www.wertpapier-forum.de/discover/1431.xml",,,100)

 
I want to filter those results to only show rows where Column D contains any of the keywords listed in Column A of another sheet 'Keywords':
  
How would I best do this?


Below are two approaches. Because column D of your feed results contains characters that make it tricky to work with QUERY with MATCHES, I recommend using the FILTER approach.
FILTER
This is the recommended approach for your use case.
=LET(url, "https://www.wertpapier-forum.de/discover/1431.xml",
  feed, IMPORTFEED(url), keys, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Keywords!A:A), 
  FILTER(feed, REGEXMATCH(INDEX(feed, , 4), "(?i)"& keys)))
FILTER  IMPORTFEED  INDEX  LET  REGEXMATCH  TEXTJOIN
QUERY
Uses IMPORTFEED() as a placeholder for your current formula. Some of the characters in your actual data may cause problems for this approach.
=QUERY(IMPORTFEED(), "WHERE Col4 MATCHES 
   '.*("& TEXTJOIN("|", 1, keywords!A:A)& ").*'")
QUERY  IMPORTFEED  TEXTJOIN

Very good answer, thank you!

Is it possible to show in a separate column against which keyword each row matched?

Absolutely. Please ask a new question with the details of what you want and the community will help you. You can also  add a link to it here in a comment if you want me to be notified.
